# ring of endomorphism of rational numbers

Tags: algebraic-topology

I want to find End$(Q,+,0)$ which as I know is a ring of maps like $\mu$: $Q$ $\to$ $Q$ and satisfy the following axioms.

1. $\mu(x+y)=\mu(x)+\mu(y)$
2. $\mu(mx)=m\mu(x)$

and also I've seen that $\mu$ determines by its effect on the set of generator of $Q$.
but I can't figure out where to start.

Comment: Can you find lots of examples of endomorphisms?

Comment: the only one I seems to find is the identity map. @LordSharktheUnknown

Comment: Do you think that  $\mu ( x )=3/2 \cdot x$ satisfies the conditions? By the way, by  $m$, do you mean an arbitrary integer? If so, do you think that property 2 holds with $m$ an arbitrary rational number?

Comment: @peterag yes both conditions are OK with this definition. $\mu(mx)=m\mu(x)$ for any integer $m$ so if we define $\mu(1)=q$ or any rational number $q$ the conditions are satisfied so the ring of End($Q$,+,0) will be also $Q$ right?

Comment: @ParisaMahmoudi - That is right. Once you show that the linearity property holds with $m$ rational if it holds for $m$ integral,  then the map $\mu$ is determined by what $\mu $ does to $1$: for $m\in {\mathbb Q}$, $$\mu ( m ) = \mu ( m\cdot 1 ) = m \mu ( 1 ).$$

Comment: @peterag thanks a lot for your clarification. .